# How to place value in column A if it exist in another table, otherwise, place in column B

Tags: sql, t-sql

I got a lookup list table of valid US state abbreviations and a source table:

**States** lookup and **Source** tables respectively

```
+-------+    +-----------------+
|States |    |ID | Location    |
+=======+    +=================+
| AK    |    | 1 | Madrid      |
---------    -------------------
| AL    |    | 2 | AK          |
---------    -------------------
| AR    |    | 3 | AR          |
---------    -------------------
| ...   |    | ..| ...         |
---------    -------------------
```

How do I create an INSERT statement into a **Target** table such that if `Location` is a valid state, it will be placed in the `State` column and if it's not, it would be placed in the `Other Locale` column?

Expected **Target** table output

```
+------------+-----------------
|ID | State  | Other Locale   |
+============+=================
| 1 |        | Madrid         |
-------------------------------
| 2 | AK     |                |
-------------------------------
| 3 | AR     |                |
-------------------------------
| ..| ...    | ...            |
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody has suggested using NULLIF i might as well throw that in.

```
DECLARE @Location TABLE (Id INT, Location VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @States TABLE (States VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Location VALUES
(1, 'Madrid'), (2, 'AK'), (3, 'AR')

INSERT INTO @States VALUES
('AK'), ('AL'), ('AR')


SELECT  l.Id,
        s.States [State],
        NULLIF(l.Location,s.States) [Other Locale]
FROM    @Location l
        LEFT JOIN @States s ON l.Location = s.States
```

Comment: I like that :-) You just have to think twice about the logic, the CASE is a bit easier to grasp.

Comment: I like this one. I actually find this simpler to understand than using a Case statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do a LEFT JOIN and check for NULLs due to non-matching states:

```
insert into target
select source.id, states.state,
   case when states.state is null then location end as Other_Locale
from source left join states 
  on source.location = states.state
```

Comment: I really don't get it. We literally have the same answer, I was a few minutes quicker and posted a working sample as well. How did you get upvotes when I didn't? Are you seeing anything I'm missing here?

Comment: @Amit: Don't know, maybe because your first CASE is not needed at all?

Comment: Maybe.. I thought it's clearer this way since the question was about conditional values (A / B), but perhaps you're right, that can deter some votes :-)

Comment: @Amit + 0.5 for a fiddle, -0.5 for useless case *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

You could use an left join and pick the column value depending on match:

```
SELECT so.ID, CASE WHEN States.States IS NOT NULL THEN so.Location END,
       CASE WHEN States.States IS NULL THEN so.Location END
FROM Source so LEFT JOIN States
  ON States.States = so.Location
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e348e/2)

Then of course you can insert that to whatever table you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a case statement; something like this (roughly)

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.ResultsTable
        SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                                   FROM     StatesTable
                                   WHERE    States = l.Location ) THEN l.Location
                     ELSE NULL
                END AS [State] ,
                CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS ( SELECT   1
                                       FROM     StatesTable
                                       WHERE    States = l.Location ) THEN l.Location
                     ELSE NULL
                END AS [Other Locale]
        FROM    dbo.LocationsTable l
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
INSERT INTO Target (State , Other Locale) 
SELECT Location , ""  FROM Source Where Location IN 
(SELECT States FROM States) UNION
SELECT "" , Location FROM Source Where Location NOT IN 
(SELECT States FROM States) ;
```

Maybe depending on the database or config you would need to use AS to Name the columns like :

```
INSERT INTO Target (State , Other Locale) 
    SELECT Location AS "State" , "" AS " Other Locale"
 FROM Source Where Location IN (SELECT States FROM States) UNION
    SELECT "" AS "State", Location AS " Other Locale" 
FROM Source Where Location NOT IN (SELECT States FROM States) ;
```

Comment: use union all, there is no way the implied distinct will do anything

Comment: Thanks for the comment ! My SQL skills are a little bit rusty :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be the long way, but it's easier (for me anyways) to read & troubleshoot:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spLocations (@inLocation varchar(255))
AS
-- declare local variables
declare @col_name nvarchar(255) = ''
declare @location nvarchar(255) = ''

SELECT @location = [colState] from tblStates where [colState] = @inLocation;

SET @col_name = CASE @location 
                    WHEN Null     
                        THEN 'State'
                    ELSE 'Other Locale'
                END;
INSERT INTO targetTBL ([' + @col_name + ']) VALUES (@inLocation);
GO;
```

Comment: I don't think `INSERT INTO targetTBL ([' + @col_name + ']) VALUES (@inLocation);` does what you think it does. Are you really proposing dynamic SQL?

Comment: Yup, as an alternative I am suggesting dynamic SQL. But you're right, I forgot to put it into a var (@SQLQuery) and the line  `EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @col_name, @location;`